# JavaFX CSS Sheet is not working—Unknown Property

Tags: css, eclipse, javafx

[JavaFX Entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4Jjx.png)[image: Example]

I just installed JavaFX for Eclipse; and so far, it's working. When I want to edit the CSS Stylesheet, there is for every file the message: "Unknown Property"—with the yellow sign.
What need I to do in this case? I think JavaFX should be installed corectly, because all other is working.

Comment: Show us an example

Comment: Ok, i took a Snapshot. I hope this is a common Error. When i toggle over the yellow sign there is the warning: Unknown Property

Comment: With which editor do you open what file?

Comment: This is in Eclipse. And i use here the automatically added CSS application file

Comment: Sure, it is in Eclipse. If you right-click the CSS file, in _Open With_ you can choose an editor. Based on the chosen editor you will get different warnings and code completion. (In the screenshot the editor icon is cropped, so it is unclear if you choose the correct editor.)

Comment: Ah okay i didnt know that. Its opened in the e(fx)clipse CSS editor. Is this the right one?

Comment: @jlaenzlinger Yes. Does the project have a
_JavaFX SDK_ library entry? See https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=814905&goto=1426890&#msg_1426890

Comment: I added another Screenshot. Do you mean this entry?

Comment: @jlaenzlinger Yes. Does moving the _JavaFX SDK_ library entry from the _Modulepath_ to the _Classpath_ change something?

Comment: @howlger no, the fx modules _must_ be on the module path - wondering why there're two fx entries, one on the class- the other on the module path? How do they differ? Anyway, you should have exactly one, and that on the module path.

Comment: okey then i have it correct, but still wondering why its not working. I go crazy

Comment: Those are just warnings that eclipse does not know about those properties.That does not mean that JavaFX isn't able to work with this CSS file...

Comment: And how can I teach Eclipse what properties there are?

Comment: @howlger Ok wow, I figured it out finally. The Problem was probably, that the Path to the Files was not correct. I had to change the Path, and then after running the functioning project the alert were gone. Is it possible to change this question to awnsered?

Comment: @kleopatra To my knowledge the entries must be on the modulepath if and only if using JPMS (= having a `module-info.java` file). Independent of that, I was wondering what effects that has on the CSS editor, even if it leads to errors in Java files.

Comment: @aeiouaeoeue can you explain which file path were wrong? i am facing the same issue. stuck with this for more than week now, trying all possible ways.